# How much of werewolf "folk lore" can be attributed to the invention of Curt Siodmak?

Tags: werewolf

I know the poem about "a man who is pure at heart" turning into a wolf was written by Siodmak but I am not sure, like Stoker, how much Siodmak himself was inspired by European folk lore. It may be that silver bullets and other things all come from his imagination.

Comment: This might be a bit too broad as it stands, because what's part of "werewolf folk lore" isn't necessarily clearly defined. Can you narrow down to some more specific aspects (e.g. silver bullets, maybe?)

Comment: Rather than "How much", I'd just "What aspects" for the question so that it's definite points rather than a general proportion. But that may just be me.